# Optional feature module angular-cli

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I'm trying to use architecture like below:

```
module-name
|
+-- service
|    | pom.xml
|    | src
+-- web
|    | *.ts
+-- index.ts // barrell file
webapp
|
+-- src
|    | app.module.ts
|    | main.ts
|    | tsconfig.app.json
.angular-cli.json
tsconfig.json
```

If `tsconfig` from .angular-cli.json is set to `webapp/src/tsconfig.app.json`, using `ng serve` works as expected but for `ng build --prod`

it generates error:

> ERROR in /some_absolute_path/webapp/src/$$_gendir/module/web-utils/web/section/section.component.ngfactory.ts (13,21): Cannot find module './section.component'.

For each file in `webapp/src`.

On the other hand, after switching angular-cli to use `./tsconfig.json` AOT works fine but `ng serve` causes endless compilation.

Comment: "tsconfig from .angular-cli.json is set to webapp/src/tsconfig.app.json", Try changing that to `tsconfig.app.json`. Might work!

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not. Just take a look at files structure (`tsconfig.app.json` is inside `webapp/src`, while `.angular-cli.json` is project root)

Comment: Where it differs from a normal cli project is `tsconfig.app.json` is inside 'src' folder which is inside the 'webapp' folder. In normal cli app, it's inside 'src' and '.angular-cli.json' has the `tsconfig: tsconfig.app.json`
So obviously it's something to do with the path it seems.

Comment: There is no denying that it is connected with paths. But I don't how to set them to make app and AOT working properly

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create a sample application with

```
ng new app-name
```

and compare the configurations and paths inside the generated files.